# Delphi to C# WinForms: Iterate through form components on form

Tags: c#, winforms, delphi

In Delphi you can iterate through a forms components (**not controls**) like so:

```
for i := 0 to Form1.ComponentCount - 1 do begin
```

However in c# Winforms i tried the following:

```
        foreach (var component in this.components.Components)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(component.ToString());
        }
```

I couldn't find any examples on google on how to iterate through components. All i found was how to iterate through controls.

I want to list all controls and components on a form.
For example if there are 2 buttons and 2 imagelists i want to list all 4 items.

Comment: What is a Component in Delphi? What makes it different to a Control?

Comment: a component in delphi can be anything, an editbox but also a imagelist for example. They are all maintained in the same collection. The list of Components has all components owned by the given component, the list of Controls has all components that are parented by the given component that is the only difference

Comment: @simonatrcl Similar to C#.  A control is a subclass of component that encompases all visual components.  Components that are not visual components (ie: not Controls) can be added and configured at design time but have no visual elements.  They are represented in the designer with icons that are not visible at runtime.

Comment: In Delphi there are no controls, only components. Some are visual others are not but they are all callled components

Comment: @GuidoG Not so. By control in Delphi we mean anything descended from `TControl`. These are visual and their identifying characteristic is that they have a `Parent`.

Comment: @Thomas it's often not very useful to iterate through a Delphi form's components. The form can have visual controls that are not found in the form's components. The `Components[]` property relates to lifetime management. It's just a coincidence that much of the time all the visual controls on the form, and its children are also found in `Components[]`.

Comment: All is descendant from TObject and only later on there is a seperation in visual and non visual components. In all the years I used Delphi we called it visual components and non visual components. The term controls is introduced when visual studio arrived I guess

Comment: No, @GuidoG (do we know each other?), `TControl` existed in Delphi 1. `TControl` is a component that has a parent. There are `TWinControl`s and `TGraphicControl`s.

Comment: @Thomas When you move from one framework to another, not all concepts transfer literally. I very much suspect that you should be trying to work out how best to solve your problem in the new framework, rather than trying to impose a solution from a different framework.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yes we might had some chats back in the old B Team days on the delphi forum. TControl has always existed I never said it did not. I just never heard anybody saying controls in Delphi only components. That is what I am saying.

Comment: When I said they are seperated later i did not mean in a later version of Delphi, i mean in the object hierarchy of Delphi. There is a misunderstanding here in what I was saying. Some components are descendant from TWinControls others from TGraphicControl if I remember correct ? But all are born as TObject or am I really have forgotten all about Delphi ?

Comment: You have forgotten a lot. Both TGraphicControl and TWinControl descend from TControl. And yes, controls are often called controls, even in Delphi.

Comment: And where does TControl inherits from ? TPersistent which is inherited from TObject ? if I remember correctly. In the Borland courses they where never called controls (I gave them up to delphi 5). The first time I learned the term controls was in visual studio. Anyway where are getting off topic here what I was trying to explain was that unlike visual studio where you have 2 collections one for controls and one for components it is only one in Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not easy in c#
Also be very carefull when you use inherited forms.
Unlike Delphi the unvisual designer has no support for oop when it comes to the components collection, there is a new collection created for every form even for descendants !

I did it like this : (it will only list components not controls !)

```
IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents()
{
    return from field in GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
               where typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)
               let component = (Component)field.GetValue(this)
               where component != null
               select component;
    }
```

you can call it like this :

```
foreach (Component component in EnumerateComponents())
{
    if (component is ImageList)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Results in a System.ArgumentException for me. 'Field '<ParentControl>k__BackingField' defined on type 'blah' is not a field on the target object which is of type 'blah